# How do I load the Google News API without google.load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-api, google.load

I want to load the Google News API without using google.load. which menas I need this as a simple script block.

E-g Maps can be loaded via

First Approach:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 
google.load("maps", "2");
```

OR

Second Approach: `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>`

In the same way google news API can be loaded via

First Approach:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 
    google.load('search', '1');
```

Second Approach:  I dont know, thats the question

**So My question is how do I load a Google News API without google.load,**

Comment: An interesting question. **1.** How did you discover the second approach for the maps API? **2.** Why do you need to avoid using `google.load`?

Comment: 1: https://developers.google.com/loader/
2: I am using multiple of APIS in one APP, and if I do google.load it creates a conflict within them.

Comment: *"I am using multiple of APIS in one APP, and if I do google.load it creates a conflict within them.*" - That sounds to me like a more fundamental problem to be addressed. I would have thought that if running `google.load` is causing conflicts, manually loading the resources would be just as likely to conflict?